# One-to-many relationships in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying  to design the schema for an app that I am creating, but I am having difficulty figuring out how to do one-to-many relationships.

This is a school app where students will register into a course and tutorial.

```
var CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    code: { type: String,  required: true, unique: true },
    tutorials: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Tutorial' }]
});

var TutorialSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    number: { type: String, required: true },
    students: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Student' }]
});

var StudentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: { type: String, required: true },
    lastName: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true } 
});
```

Simple enough.

Now, what if I want to add a feature that will allow students within the same tutorial to be part of groups. Some tutorials will have group-based work and some not.

One way I can think of doing it is to add a `groups` field as an array of references to groups.

```
var TutorialSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    number: { type: String, required: true },
    students: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Student' }],
    groups: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Group' }]
});

var GroupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    number: { type: Int, required: true },
    students: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Student' }]
});
```

Should I worry about data duplication? Is there a better approach?